# Bulkloader import list of integers

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

How should I configure import_transform and export_transform im my configuration yaml file to be able to export and import multiple integer property?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this collection of helpers for bulk loading data:

http://code.google.com/p/bulkloader-gdata-connector/source/browse/bulk_helper.py

I think that list_to_json(int) and json_to_list(int) are what you need.

Be aware that this will choke on entities that have don't have the list defined yet.